# Why does using a parameter name other the index result in Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'

Tags: swift

Take the two snippets below, the top one works fine but the bottom one results in
Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'

**using index** ✅

```swift
extension Array {
    subscript(i index: Int) -> (String, String)? {
        guard let value = self[index] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        
        switch (value >= 0, abs(value % 2)) {
        case (true, 0): return ("positive", "even")
        case(true, 1): return ("positive", "odd")
        case(false, 0): return ("negative", "even")
        case(false, 1): return ("negative", "odd")
        default: return nil
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Without using index** ❌

```swift
extension Array {
    subscript(i: Int) -> (String, String)? {
        guard let value = self[i] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        
        switch (value >= 0, abs(value % 2)) {
        case (true, 0): return ("positive", "even")
        case(true, 1): return ("positive", "odd")
        case(false, 0): return ("negative", "even")
        case(false, 1): return ("negative", "odd")
        default: return nil
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the name `index` is irrelevant to the problem; it could be any name.

The actual problem is that [`Array` already has a subscript that takes an unlabeled `Int`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540606-subscript)

Your first overload does not have the same input signature. Instead, it requires an argument label:

```swift
[1][i: 0] // ("positive", "odd")
```

You *can* still use an overload without a label…

```swift
extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger {
  subscript(: Int) -> (String, String) {
    let value: Element = self[]
    return (
      value >= 0 ? "positive" : "negative",
      value.isMultiple(of: 2) ? "even" : "odd"
    )
  }
}
```

…but then, as is necessary within the subscript body itself, you'll need to always explicitly type the result, in order to access the overload from the standard library, because whatever you have in your own module is going to take precedence.

```swift
[1][0] // ("positive", "odd")
[1][0] as Int // 1
```

So, I recommend either using a subscript with a label, or a method.*

---

* What I *would like to* recommend is a named subscript. But Swift doesn't have them. You can emulate them with more types, however. Like this:

```swift
extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger {
  struct InfoStrings {
    fileprivate let array: Array
  }

  var infoStrings: InfoStrings { .init(array: self) }
}

extension Array.InfoStrings {
  subscript(index: Int) -> (String, String) {
    let value = array[index]
    return (
      value >= 0 ? "positive" : "negative",
      value.isMultiple(of: 2) ? "even" : "odd"
    )
  }
}

[1].infoStrings[0]
```